# Page and content not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been struggling with this for days. It is not responsive on mobile as well as when resizing a browser.

I'm trying run this as a frame on Google sites, but the lack of responsiveness makes it even worse when viewed.
Any pointers to what I'm missing? 
This is what I've done so far.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-device-width:800px){ }
#chart_div {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/pZYVjgQ/testbgm.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 1048px;
padding-left: 80px !important;
padding-top: 85px;

}
#chart_div table {
padding: 11px !important;
}
#chart_div2 {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/pZYVjgQ/testbgm.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
#chart_div2 table {
padding: 11px !important;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {

     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Label', 'Value'],
       ['Weekly', 80],
       // ['Monthly', 80],
     ]);

     var options = {
       width: 640, height: 420,
       // redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
       // yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
       minorTicks: 5
     };

     var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

     chart.draw(data, options);

     setInterval(function() {
       data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }, 13000);
   }
 </script>
</head>
<body style="height: 90vh;display: flex; justify-content:center; flex-direction: column; align-items:center; background: #AARRGGBB">
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;" class="container-fluid"></div>
    <!--<img src="https://i.ibb.co/pZYVjgQ/testbgm.png" alt="team" border="0"style="width:40%">-->
</body>
</html>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

You have `@media screen and (max-device-width:800px){ }` - This will do nothing at all: You are immediately closing the curly bracket after opening it.

Also, better use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width` for media queries AND (in a desktop-first stylesheet) place the media queries *after*  the general CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, created more CSS and JS scripts with 'if' statements to resize the page if opened on tablets, desktop or mobile.